# merge two dataframes and add column level with names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I've been digging through the concat, join, and merge methods for pandas and can't seem to find what I want.

Lets assume I have two dataframes

```
A = pd.DataFrame("A",index=[0,1,2,3,4],columns=['Col 1','Col 2','Col 3'])
B = pd.DataFrame("B",index=[0,1,2,3,4],columns=['Col 1','Col 2','Col 3'])
>>> A
  Col 1 Col 2 Col 3
0     A     A     A
1     A     A     A
2     A     A     A
3     A     A     A
4     A     A     A
>>> B
  Col 1 Col 2 Col 3
0     B     B     B
1     B     B     B
2     B     B     B
3     B     B     B
4     B     B     B
```

Now I want to make a new dataframe with the columns merged, I think its easiest to explain if I make a multi index for how I want the columns

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([A.columns.values,['A','B']])
>>> index
MultiIndex(levels=[['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'], ['A', 'B']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Now if I make an empty dataframe with this multi index for the columns

```
empty_df = pd.DataFrame('-',index=A.index,columns=index)
>>> empty_df
  Col 1    Col 2    Col 3
      A  B     A  B     A  B
0     -  -     -  -     -  -
1     -  -     -  -     -  -
2     -  -     -  -     -  -
3     -  -     -  -     -  -
4     -  -     -  -     -  -
```

My question is, what merge, concat, or join do I use to obtain that? I've tried multiple things for concat...inner,outer etc. I can't seem to find what I want. Only thing I can think of is making the empty dataframe and then back filling.

Edit: After trying out Jezrael's response, it is close but not it exactly. What I want is like nested columns of sort? For example

```
empty_df['Col 1']
>>> empty_df['Col 1']
   A  B
0  -  -
1  -  -
2  -  -
3  -  -
4  -  -
```

Or

```
>>> empty_df['Col 1']['A']
0    -
1    -
2    -
3    -
4    -
Name: A, dtype: object
```

So this is a solution I've come up with but its from iterating over the columns.

```
row_idx = A.index.union(B.index)
col_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([A.columns.values,['A','B']])
new_df = pd.DataFrame('-',index=row_idx,columns=col_idx)
for column in A.columns:
   new_df.loc[:,(column,'A')] = A[column]
   new_df.loc[:,(column,'B')] = B[column]
>>> new_df
  Col 1    Col 2    Col 3
      A  B     A  B     A  B
0     A  B     A  B     A  B
1     A  B     A  B     A  B
2     A  B     A  B     A  B
3     A  B     A  B     A  B
4     A  B     A  B     A  B
>>> new_df['Col 1']
   A  B
0  A  B
1  A  B
2  A  B
3  A  B
4  A  B
>>> new_df['Col 1']['A']
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    A
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `keys` parameter and `axis=1`, last change order of levels by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and sorting by first level by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = (pd.concat([A, B], axis=1, keys=('A','B'))
         .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=0))
print (df1)
  Col 1    Col 2    Col 3   
      A  B     A  B     A  B
0     A  B     A  B     A  B
1     A  B     A  B     A  B
2     A  B     A  B     A  B
3     A  B     A  B     A  B
4     A  B     A  B     A  B
```

For working with [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) is possible use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (df1.xs('Col 1', axis=1, level=0))
   A  B
0  A  B
1  A  B
2  A  B
3  A  B
4  A  B
```

If want select `MultiIndex column` use `tuple`:

```
print (df1[('Col 1', 'A')])
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    A
Name: (Col 1, A), dtype: object
```

If want select by index and by column use `loc`:

```
print (df1.loc[4, ('Col 1', 'A')])
A
```